# How can I use the $timeout and $interval that was used in angular.js but for the Angular version?

Tags: angular

In Angular.js I used `$timeout` and `$interval` (similar to  `setInterval` and `setTimeout` in javascript).

```
$timeout(function(){})
$interval(function(){},5000)
```

to cancel the interval I used

```
$interval.cancel($scope.interval);
```

and when leaving the view and avoiding that the `$interval` was still running I used. I am new at Angular.

```
$scope.$on('$ destroy', function () {
   $interval.cancel($scope.interval)
})
```

How can I use the equivalent of these 2 functions that I used in angular.js to angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setInterval` & `setTimeout` as is inside Angular, but use `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle hook to clear the timers stuff before component instance is diminished. This lifecycle hook helps to clearing the stuff, it is as similar as that of angularjs `$destroy` event.

```
ngOnDestroy(){
  //do clear intervals and timeouts here
  //clearInterval(yourInterval);
  //clearTimeout(yourTimeout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout native function. There is no special services in angular to handle timers.